# Magento 2 Creating custom homepage

Tags: magento2

I've just started on magento 2, read (most) of the documentation and started my project. I want to create custom homepage first with my own header/section/footer (NOT the one that comes by default). I already have it done through html&css like static stuff so I "just" need to make it magento 2 way..

Untill now I have created a theme, registered it, chose it and in my theme folder I have Magento_Theme folder which contains page_layout folder and layouts.xml. Page_layouts folder contains homepage.xml

so my homepage.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

and my layouts.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="homepage">
        <label translate="true">Custom Homepage</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

When I navigate to admin / content / pages I can set my layout to Home page, but when i comment out `<container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />` from homepage.xml it changes nothing.

How can I remove magento header/footer content on homepage.xml and add my own html&css? Would be awesome if someone can give me a simplest example that will add a `<div>test</div>` to my homepage.xml so when I go to localhost I only get that div, withuot magento header/footer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is still showing header and footer is because you have the containers defined in your `homepage.xml`, if you look at `module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` you can see which blocks are included in `header.container`, `page.top` and `footer-container`.

Only leaving the `empty` handle would give you a clean slate while still having access to `content` for reference. You could also define your own custom containers here.

You can still reference the container `content` and add your custom Blocks or Widgets from there or do it from admin in Content > Pages.